# Groups of 3 from 12 numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I need groups of $3$ numbers from $12$ without any repetition and I need $4$ sets of these groups of $3$ numbers. e.g. $1,2,3~~~4,5,6~~~7,8,9~~~10,11,12$ is the obvious first set of groups of $3$ numbers from $12$. I need $3$ more sets without any repetition. So, $1, 2, 4$ is a group of $3$ that has a repeat (it appears in the first group $1,2,3$).  Therefore, the number $1$ must not appear with the number $2$ or the number $3$ again in any of the $4$ sets of numbers.

I have tried this manually and to arrange three sets is easy. The problem is arranging the $4$th set without any repeats.

Help me please !

---

*Edit by @JMoravitz: In order to avoid this question reaching its fifth "closed as unclear what you are asking vote," here is a rewording of my understanding of the problem*

Does there exist, and if so exhibit, a family of sixteen sets $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4,B_1,B_2,\dots,C_1,\dots,D_1,\dots,D_4$, each of which a three-element subset of $\{1,2,\dots,12\}$ such that $\bigcup A_i=\bigcup B_i=\bigcup C_i=\bigcup D_i = \{1,2,\dots,12\}$ such that any two of the sets have intersection empty or of size one.

Comment: Perhaps you should look into the possibility that such an arrangement doesn't exist.  In the case that we had $15$ or $13$ numbers instead of $12$, this problem could be reduced to that of finding a [Steiner Triple System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system) or the [Kirkman's Schoolgirl Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman's_schoolgirl_problem).  Since $12$ is a multiple of six however, it makes it more difficult.

Comment: Another search term that might be useful is ["edge disjoint triangle packing"](https://www.google.com/search?q=partition+k_12+into+edge+disjoint+triangles&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=edge+disjoint+triangle+packing).  [This paper](http://tinyurl.com/hgzmuf7) suggests that you could find up to twenty triples (you require only 16) but doesn't say anything about those triples having the property that every number appears the same number of times...

Comment: @M.Vinay What he wants is *related to* a steiner triple system (already mentioned in my first comment) however this problem is technically different.  He does not require that every possible pair be present in some system.  In a steiner triple system, every possible pair $\{x,y\}$ must be present in some triple in the system.  This is a relaxed version of that problem.

Comment: I thought it was clear. I want 4 sets of 12 numbers, divided into groups of three so that each set contains no repetitions. So, Set 1 would be as follows;